# FastAPI, python, get - pass variable from different function

Tags: python, fastapi

In file1 (fast_api file):

```
app = Fast API(title='myapp', docs_url='/', description="some_desc")
app.test = "In file1"

def run_fastapi(context):
    uvicorn.run("api:app", reload=False)

@app.get("/api/some_value", responses=SOME_RESPONSES)
def get_parcels(response: Response):
    test = app.store
    print(test)
```

then in file2:
I want to be able to do:

```
import file1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file1.app.store = "In file2"
    file1.app.run_fastapi()
```

But every time I am getting "in File1", how can i modify my code to be able to change value of app.test inside file2?

Comment: Can you share your directory structure?

Comment: It's pretty much like that File1 and File and __init__ inside a folder and that's it :)

Comment: I think you need to change value of  reload parameter in uvicorn.run to True, in order to reload dynamically after changes saved in files

Comment: that doesn't work